# core data( retrieving data between users)on an app

Tags: ios, core-data

iam new to iOS development 
i have built a simple app (chat,posts,images,audio,and so on) which seems to be a simple social media between users (retrieving data with each other using core data) ...when i started to code this app ... i start for training on core data, i had no intension about app store , but now :) if i improve my app to put it to app store... is this idea of retrieving data between user succeed ? if a user has his own device ,his friend has his own device also .. could they retrieve data from one file ? could sqlite for core data saved on a device ... would be as another device with the same simulator as(iPhone 7) ?my code is programmatically good and app is nice ....if your answer is no ... so what is the requirements to publish it on app store ? .... if your answer is no at any case ... please tell me that ... thanks in advance ... i would like that i have't asked a naive questions :)

Comment: Core data only saves data locally, on the device. For different users on different devices you will need some sort of server datastore. You could use CloudKit or Firebase or one of many others.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you :)